# Cloning CodeCommit repository to another AWS account using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-codecommit

I have two AWS accounts. I develop code in one CodeCommit repository. Once it is done, I need to clone that code into the other account CodeCommit repository. Is there a way to do that using lambda function or any other method to automate the process.

Please help me, it was a really a headache more than a month. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways doing that. Essentially, what you'll need is a trigger, that then kicks of the replication process into another account after each commit. Below are two possible ways documented doing this.

**Lambda + Fargate**

The first one uses a combination of Lambda, which you can select CodeCommit to be a trigger for. The Lambda function then runs a Fargate task, which in turn replicates the repository using `git clone --mirror`. Fargate is used here as the replication of larger repositories might exceed the temporary storage that Lambda can allocate.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/replicate-aws-codecommit-repository-between-regions-using-aws-fargate/

**CodePipeline + CodeBuild**

This is probably the "cleaner" variant as it uses native CI/CD tooling in AWS, making it easier to set up as compared to ECS/Fargate, amongst other advantages.

Here you're setting up AWS CodePipeline, which will monitor the CodeCommit repository for any changes. When a commit is detected, it will trigger CodeBuild, which in turn runs the same git command outlined earlier.

https://medium.com/geekculture/replicate-aws-codecommit-repositories-between-regions-using-codebuild-and-codepipeline-39f6b8fcefd2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have repo 1 on account A, repo 2 on account B, you want to sync repo 1 -> repo 2

The easiest way is to do the following:

1. create SNS topic on Account A
2. enable Notification for repo 1, and send all event to SNS topic
3. create a lambda function to subscribe the SNS topic
4. make sure you followed this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html to grant lambda function cross account CodeCommit permission
5. write a python function to decide what git events you want to replicate. If you just want to sync the `main` branch and ignore all other branch, you can say something like: `if event["source_ref"].endswith("main")`, then use boto3 CodeCommit API https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html, (take a look at `batch_get_commits`) to commit the change to the remote CodeCommit repo.

However, I really doubt that do you really need to do this? How about just dump the all git history as a zip to S3 to your remote account? and just import everytime if you see any changes? I believe your remote account is mostly READ ONLY and just serve as a backup. If you only need backup, you can just dump to S3 and don't even need to import.